# Is it possible to remove the Android smileys that replace text strings like ":)"?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-nexus, samsung-galaxy-s-3, 4.2-jelly-bean

A friend of mine was wondering if it's possible to remove or replace these smileys entirely, or if they are a native function of the Android operating system that would require tweaks in a custom ROM to get rid of. Question applies to both tagged devices (S3 and Galaxy Nexus).

These are the smileys we are talking about, for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of the particular app that you are using. If you are referring to the SMS Messaging app, there are various [SMS apps replacements](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=sms&c=apps) available on Google Play, you can customize the smiley on some SMS replacement apps or disable them entirely.